# Delivering PushNotification, FCM, to multiple apps by the same Firebase project

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Scenario:**

One device, has many apps, by the same Firebase project.
On delivering notifications, only the last application to install, will receive notifications.

**How:**

Delivering by push token

**Question:**

Does Firebase FCM support this? Or I would have to move every app to a different project (A lot of client and server work... trying to avoid this)

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple apps to one FCM account/Firebase project but there is one restriction, bundle identifier of all app not same.

**As you said "On delivering notifications, only the last application to install, will receive notifications"**

**Suggestion:-**  If the bundle identifier of all apps is not same then you will send notification using bundle identifier but if your app live with that identifier then that notification will go to all install apps.

**Delivering by push token**

**Suggestion:-** As you said that you send notification by FCM Push Token then it goes only that app you get that token. Because you get a push token for a particular device for a particular app. So, this notification only goes to that particular app.

**Does Firebase FCM support this? Or I would have to move every app to a different project (A lot of client and server work... trying to avoid this)**

**Suggestion:-** Yes, FCM supports this. NO, You don't need to create multiple accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your description answer, the apps do use different bundle identifier, do you have experience with this? And for you did it work seamlessly?

Comment: We are having a similar problem, bundleIds are also different, Apps are even installed on different devices with different accounts but the token of one app was immediately invalid with: messaging/registration-token-not-registered even though the app was newly installed